# CSS tag 'right' does not work as expected when using percentages

Tags: html, css

When trying to use the `right` tag in CSS it does not work as I might expect. I was trying to make a page where one div would be so many pixels from the left, and extend 100% of the way to the right by using

```
left: 200px;
right: 100%;
```

This has worked before but for some reason it does not work now becuase the box that is drawn is only 75 - 100px in width. I have no width tag defined and I also have no height tag but instead a top tag with no bottom tag to match (unsure if that helps)

Any ideas? Or is more information required?

Comment: CSS has no "tags". Please show the actual CSS selectors and properties.

Answer (score 4):

`right` value means distance from right edge of nearest positioned ancestor element to right edge of positioned element.

`right: 0` is probably what you need instead of `right: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute; right: 100%;` will push left 100% out of the parents width. 
http://codepen.io/Nunotmp/pen/wdKAx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what tags you are using, but it may be an issue of the display value being `inline` or something other that `block`.

I don't think it is going to work for you to use the `left: 200px` this is the result that you'll get with that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltvkg/

You might try something like this though: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltvkg/1/